# How to verify a GCR image to be binary authorized or attested as per a policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

With [Binary Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/overview) in GCP we can secure deployments to run authorized GCR images. However I'm looking for some API or where I can pro-grammatically verify a GCR image if it is attested before deploying a container. I have searched for this but couldn't find any API or resource for this. Any ideas how I can achieve this ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is [this gcloud command and equivalent REST](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/making-attestations#verify_that_the_attestation_was_created) in-order to verify the attestation is  created or not. Is this something you are looking for? If not, I would strongly recommend you to report it as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)  by mentioning your use case scenario and re-production step(if any)

Comment: Actually I am looking for some REST API wherein I can pass the GCR image digest or version tag and verify if it is attested

Comment: I am not sure whether there is an all in one [rest API](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/reference/rest) to support what you are looking for. I believe you need to request it as a new [feature](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/overview#features).